# R keep crashing for my Random forest model because I want to grow 10,000 trees and have do.omit of 1,000

Tags: r, random-forest

I have some NA value in my dataset, I have taken them out with na.omit. I have run my out-of-bag error rate for my Random Forest model with the number of trees at 1000 and do.trace at 100,  but my RStudio keeps crashing when I want to grow 10,000 trees and I want to trace every 1000 trees. I don't know what to do...

This is what R studio tells me : 
[image]

This is my code :

```
    attach(Part_I_swiping_data)
    Part_I_swiping_data_na_omit <-na.omit(Part_I_swiping_data)
    myforest_3J =        randomForest(swipe~age_swiper+age_candidate+looking_for_swiper+gender_swiper
    +photo_candidate+photo_with_other_people+photo_sun_glasses, ntree=10000, 
    data=Part_I_swiping_data_na_omit, do.trace = 1000, importance=TRUE)

    myforest_3J
```

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "crashing"?

Comment: I have added the message @42-

Answer (score 0):

When a similar error was reported in the RStudio forum, there was the suspicion by the respondent that it could be related to a corrupted `.RData` file. The advice was to use Preferences (or in the case of my Linux installation  Profile/Options) to disable loading `.Rdata` files:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/the-previous-r-session-was-abnormally-terminated-due-to-an-unexpected-crash/14287

There was no response from the original poster which I suppose suggests that it may have succeeded.

I would point out that first `attach`-ing a data object and then working on it with its ordinary name makes little sense and will often result in confusion about which environment R names are being pulled from. I don't see an immediate connection with that error, but I would suggest not using `attach`.